# Matlab open dialog showing grayed out files

Tags: matlab, user-interface, modal-dialog

I am using this snippet of code to call an 'open file' dialog box in Matlab.

```
[img_file,img_path,filt] = uigetfile({ ...

        '*.bff*;*.REC*;*.mat*','Our Image Files (*.bff, *.REC, *.mat)'; ...

        '*.bff*','bff Files (*.bff)'; ...

        '*.REC*','PAR-REC Files (*.REC)'; ...

        '*.mat*','mat Files (*.mat)'}, ...

        'Select An Image File');

if filt==0

    return

end
```

The dialog opens, but **.mat** files appear grayed out (and unclickable).

I am using Matlab 7.13.0.564 on Mac Snow Leopard.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could this be the wildcard after `.mat`? Maybe that cannot be evaluated to anything useful. Have you tried just `*.mat`?

Comment: @Schorsch - that did the trick, thanks - do you want to post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the wildcard `*` *after* the file extension (e.g. `*.mat*`) The code cannot find any files that satisfy this condition - because for your `.mat`-files there is no additional character.
Hence, just use a wildcard *before* the file extension: `*.mat`